# Why does the copy of vector crash under multi-threaded operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

vector<int> v = { 1 };

int main() {
    v.reserve(100);

    thread t([] {
        while (1) {
            cout << v.size() << v.end() - v.begin(); // not crash
            cout << v[0]; // not crash
            cout << *v.begin(); // not crash
            cout << *v.end(); // not crash
            vector<int> x = v; // crash!!
        }
        });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }

    t.join();
}
```

Why does vector x = v crash without triggering double scaling?
I know this operation is dangerous. But I just want to know why it causes crash.

I do not know what happens inside.

Comment: All of this is undefined behaviour. Undefined means undefined. You might see it playing nice. You might see your program crash. You also might see the planets aligning perfectly to focus cosmic rays onto the particular spot you exist on earth to destroy your RAM and cause a blue screen.

Comment: I would imagine that the issue is something like this. 1) Memory for `x` is allocated based on current size of `v`, 2) `v` increases in size, 3) Contents of `v` are copied to `x` where they no longer fit, 4) crash.

Comment: One thread is modifying the vector (pushing and popping elements) and the other is accessing members that may be changed by the first.  Your code includes nothing that will sequence those operations.  The behaviour of your code is therefore undefined.

Comment: Please read up on [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - it "*Renders the entire program meaningless if certain rules of the language are violated.*".

Answer (score 2):

You must add some kind of synchronization mechanism when several threads access the same memory at the same time and at least one thread modify this memory.